# openvpn TLS Error: TLS handshake failed

Tags: openvpn

i installed openvpn on my vps, and the tried to login using my client.

heres my client logs when trying to connect:

```
2023-05-18 23:01:23 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:CHACHA20-POLY1305). OpenVPN ignores --cipher for cipher negotiations. 
2023-05-18 23:01:23 Note: Kernel support for ovpn-dco missing, disabling data channel offload.
2023-05-18 23:01:23 OpenVPN 2.6_git x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] [DCO]
2023-05-18 23:01:23 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022, LZO 2.10
2023-05-18 23:01:23 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
2023-05-18 23:01:23 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2023-05-18 23:01:23 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
2023-05-18 23:01:23 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2023-05-18 23:01:23 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:1194
2023-05-18 23:01:23 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
2023-05-18 23:01:23 UDPv4 link local: (not bound)
2023-05-18 23:01:23 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:1194
2023-05-18 23:01:23 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:1194, sid=cbd8aea0 e5af0cee
2023-05-18 23:01:23 net_route_v4_best_gw query: dst 0.0.0.0
2023-05-18 23:01:23 net_route_v4_best_gw result: via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1
2023-05-18 23:02:23 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
2023-05-18 23:02:23 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
2023-05-18 23:02:23 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
2023-05-18 23:02:23 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
2023-05-18 23:02:28 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
2023-05-18 23:02:28 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2023-05-18 23:02:28 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
2023-05-18 23:02:28 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2023-05-18 23:02:28 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:1194
2023-05-18 23:02:28 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
2023-05-18 23:02:28 UDPv4 link local: (not bound)
2023-05-18 23:02:28 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:1194
2023-05-18 23:02:28 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:1194, sid=f457f6e9 af59f286
2023-05-18 23:02:28 net_route_v4_best_gw query: dst 0.0.0.0
2023-05-18 23:02:28 net_route_v4_best_gw result: via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1
2023-05-18 23:03:28 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
2023-05-18 23:03:28 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
2023-05-18 23:03:28 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
2023-05-18 23:03:28 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
2023-05-18 23:03:33 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
2023-05-18 23:03:33 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2023-05-18 23:03:33 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
2023-05-18 23:03:33 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2023-05-18 23:03:33 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:443
2023-05-18 23:03:33 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->131072] S=[16384->16384]
2023-05-18 23:03:33 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:443
2023-05-18 23:03:33 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:443
2023-05-18 23:03:33 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
2023-05-18 23:03:33 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:443
2023-05-18 23:03:33 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:443, sid=0dee0970 e5d4df6b
2023-05-18 23:03:33 net_route_v4_best_gw query: dst 0.0.0.0
2023-05-18 23:03:33 net_route_v4_best_gw result: via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1
```

if any information is needed ask me and i will update the post. im new with this and don't know what to do.